# Using thousands separator and comma on decimals and formatting issues

Tags: tables, floats, formatting, siunitx, dcolumn

I am really a rookie on LaTex and would like some help with formatting the table below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage[vmargin=3cm, hmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[group-separator={.}]{siunitx}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\usepackage[group-separator={,}]{siunitx}
\begin{document}




\begin{table}[ht]
\centering\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\caption{Estat\'{i}sticas - Contribui\c{c}\~{o}es} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{4pt}}ll*{6}{d{5.2}}}
  \toprule
  {} & {}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Mediana}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Desvio Padr\~{a}o}\\
  \cmidrule(lr){3-5} 
  \cmidrule(lr){6-8} 
Ano & Vari\'{a}vel & {Controle} & {Tratado} & {Total} & {Controle} & {Tratado} & {Total} \\ 
  \midrule
2012 & Total de receitas & 3413.90 & 8645.19 & 3967.80 & 18077.13 & 94897.57 & 45339.62 \\ 
   & \hspace{4mm}Pessoas f\'{i}sicas & 300.00 & 2500.00 & 570.00 & 6201.29 & 20180.83 & 10763.53 \\ 
   & \hspace{4mm} Empresas & 0.00 & 1000.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 27854.24 & 12448.01 \\ 
   & \hspace{4mm} Partidos & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 7193.99 & 54075.33 & 24547.63 \\ 
   & \hspace{4mm} Recursos pr\'{o}prios & 1550.00 & 1850.00 & 1598.00 & 5694.75 & 12012.86 & 7382.93 \\ 
   & \hspace{4mm} Outros recursos & 91.88 & 230.00 & 103.13 & 8456.98 & 21893.65 & 12259.07 \\ \\
   & Pessoas f\'{i}sicas (\%) & 12.10 & 30.20 & 16.90 & 31.06 & 28.57 & 30.73 \\ 
   & Empresas (\%) & 0.00 & 14.20 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 24.69 & 14.21 \\ 
   & Partidos (\%) & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 9.78 & 9.50 & 9.73 \\ 
   & Recursos pr\'{o}prios (\%) & 57.90 & 22.70 & 49.90 & 36.33 & 28.93 & 36.31 \\ 
   & Outros recursos (\%) & 2.90 & 2.50 & 2.80 & 27.84 & 16.73 & 26.23 \\
   \midrule
  2016 & Total de receitas & 3600.00 & 7106.27 & 4009.00 & 11740.78 & 52605.28 & 25877.30 \\ 
   & \hspace{4mm} Pessoas f\'{i}sicas & 800.00 & 2344.70 & 1000.00 & 6136.54 & 27232.84 & 13392.53 \\ 
   & \hspace{4mm} Empresas & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
   & \hspace{4mm} Partidos & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 4343.52 & 28402.71 & 13027.55 \\ 
   & \hspace{4mm} Recursos pr\'{o}prios & 1695.00 & 3000.00 & 1857.72 & 6576.61 & 20169.18 & 10796.12 \\ 
   & \hspace{4mm} Outros recursos & 37.50 & 88.00 & 44.80 & 1544.50 & 6476.34 & 3160.15 \\ \\
   & Pessoas f\'{i}sicas (\%) & 26.70 & 37.30 & 28.90 & 31.18 & 31.46 & 31.35 \\ 
   & Empresas (\%) & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
   & Partidos (\%) & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 13.50 & 13.18 & 13.44 \\ 
   & Recursos pr\'{o}prios (\%) & 56.00 & 48.80 & 54.60 & 33.71 & 32.59 & 33.54 \\ 
   & Outros recursos (\%) & 0.70 & 0.80 & 0.80 & 20.21 & 16.07 & 19.51 \\
   \bottomrule

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I dont know why but after using the `dcolumn` package some of the column names were displayed on italic and were not aligned to their respective values. Why is that and how can it be fixed?

How can I display the numbers on the table with thousands separators and commas on the decimals? Like `1.000.000,00` for instance.

Another thing: The table is not fitting well on the PDF page using the margins that are required for the document. How can I center it and make it fit? The final document will contain a lot of other tables and I do not really understand what are the pros/cons of using `floating` options.

Really appreciate your help! Any other comments/suggestions are welcome!

Thank you!

Comment: Since you're using `siunitx` you should use the S column not the `d` column for the alignment. Try using an S column instead and adding `\sisetup{ table-format = 5.2,group-separator={.},output-decimal-marker={,}}` .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make the tabular material fit inside the text block, you should (a) remove the `@{\extracolsep{4pt}}` directives, (b) use a `tabular*` environment instead of `tabular` environment, and (c) issue the instruction `\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}` before starting the `tabular*` environment and use the directive `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` inside the header of the `tabular*` definition. That way, you'll force LaTeX calculate the best possible value of the intercolumn whitespace.

Putting these suggestions to work, I suggest you use the following setup:

```
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
     ll *{3}{S[table-format=4.2]} *{3}{S[table-format=5.2]} }
```

With regard to the formatting of the numbers: Don't load both `dcolumn` and `siunitx`. Since you wish to have LaTeX insert thousands-separators automatically, I suggest you concentrate on the `siunitx` package and its `S` column type.

The full MWE -- do note that the `times` package is deprecated; I suggest you load the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` packages:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption} % <-- new
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % <-- new
\usepackage[vmargin=3cm, hmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[group-separator={.},
            group-four-digits,
            output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % <-- new
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\caption{Estat\'{i}sticas -- Contribui\c{c}\~{o}es}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}         % <-- new
   ll *{3}{S[table-format=4.2]} *{3}{S[table-format=5.2]} } % <-- new
  \toprule
  & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Mediana} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Desvio Padr\~{a}o}\\
  \cmidrule{3-5} \cmidrule{6-8}
Ano & Vari\'{a}vel & {Controle} & {Tratado} & {Total} & {Controle} & {Tratado} & {Total} \\
  \midrule
2012 & Total de receitas & 3413.90 & 8645.19 & 3967.80 & 18077.13 & 94897.57 & 45339.62 \\
   & \hspace{4mm}Pessoas f\'{i}sicas & 300.00 & 2500.00 & 570.00 & 6201.29 & 20180.83 & 10763.53 \\
   & \hspace{4mm}Empresas & 0.00 & 1000.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 27854.24 & 12448.01 \\
   & \hspace{4mm}Partidos & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 7193.99 & 54075.33 & 24547.63 \\
   & \hspace{4mm}Recursos pr\'{o}prios & 1550.00 & 1850.00 & 1598.00 & 5694.75 & 12012.86 & 7382.93 \\
   & \hspace{4mm}Outros recursos & 91.88 & 230.00 & 103.13 & 8456.98 & 21893.65 & 12259.07 \\ 
   \addlinespace
   & Pessoas f\'{i}sicas (\%) & 12.10 & 30.20 & 16.90 & 31.06 & 28.57 & 30.73 \\
   & Empresas (\%) & 0.00 & 14.20 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 24.69 & 14.21 \\
   & Partidos (\%) & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 9.78 & 9.50 & 9.73 \\
   & Recursos pr\'{o}prios (\%) & 57.90 & 22.70 & 49.90 & 36.33 & 28.93 & 36.31 \\
   & Outros recursos (\%) & 2.90 & 2.50 & 2.80 & 27.84 & 16.73 & 26.23 \\
   \midrule
  2016 & Total de receitas & 3600.00 & 7106.27 & 4009.00 & 11740.78 & 52605.28 & 25877.30 \\
   & \hspace{4mm}Pessoas f\'{i}sicas & 800.00 & 2344.70 & 1000.00 & 6136.54 & 27232.84 & 13392.53 \\
   & \hspace{4mm}Empresas & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
   & \hspace{4mm}Partidos & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 4343.52 & 28402.71 & 13027.55 \\
   & \hspace{4mm}Recursos pr\'{o}prios & 1695.00 & 3000.00 & 1857.72 & 6576.61 & 20169.18 & 10796.12 \\
   & \hspace{4mm}Outros recursos & 37.50 & 88.00 & 44.80 & 1544.50 & 6476.34 & 3160.15 \\ 
   \addlinespace
   & Pessoas f\'{i}sicas (\%) & 26.70 & 37.30 & 28.90 & 31.18 & 31.46 & 31.35 \\
   & Empresas (\%) & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
   & Partidos (\%) & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 13.50 & 13.18 & 13.44 \\
   & Recursos pr\'{o}prios (\%) & 56.00 & 48.80 & 54.60 & 33.71 & 32.59 & 33.54 \\
   & Outros recursos (\%) & 0.70 & 0.80 & 0.80 & 20.21 & 16.07 & 19.51 \\
   \bottomrule
\end{tabular*} % <-- new
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! How can I center the table on the page?:

Comment: @ArthurCarvalhoBrito - The `tabular*` environment is defined to take up the entire width of the text block -- there's nothing left to "center" (horizontally, that is).

Answer (score 2):

Let me elaborate *AllanMunn* comment:

- for what you like is simple achievable with `S` column type from `siunitx`
- in `\sisetup{...}` define minimum number for grupoing digits
- it is sufficient to load `siunitx` ones

So, see, if the following changes of your MWE, gives, what you like to have:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[vmargin=3cm, hmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
% \small
    \centering
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\sisetup{table-format = 5.2,group-separator={.},
         group-separator={.},
         output-decimal-marker={,},
         group-four-digits}
\caption{Estat\'{i}sticas - Contribui\c{c}\~{o}es}
\begin{tabular}{ll*{6}{S}}
  \toprule
...
   \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note:*
Your table is to wide to fit in text width, even if I remove `extracolsep`.

Comment: Removing the directive `@{\extracolsep{4pt}}` may not suffice to make the tabular material fit inside the available textblock.

Comment: @Mico, I say the same. However, I didn't understand, that the table width is OP concern, so I didn't do anything beside this comment about this :(

Comment: How is it too wide?

Comment: @ArthurCarvalhoBrito, your table spill-out of right text area border. to see this, add option `showframe` to `geometry`. A good workaround you find in *Mico* answer.